# browser tab closing in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
import selenium
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
PATH="C:\Coding_projects\chromedriver.exe"
class AppleWebsite():
    def MAC():
        driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=options)
        driver.get("https://www.apple.com/fr/iphone-12/")
        MAC=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ac-globalnav"]/div/ul[2]/li[3]/a')
        MAC.click()
        time.sleep(random.randint(2,9))
        MAC_AIR=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chapternav"]/div/ul/li[2]/a')
        MAC_AIR.click()
AppleWebsite.MAC()
```

Hello, I have my selenium script in a function everything works fine but the browser tab closes as soon as the script is finished even though I don’t have a driver.quit() any idea on to solve this ?

Comment: put some sleep at the end of the script and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium always automatically quits after a code is finished running. You can add a time.sleep() to keep it open. Like this:

```py
import selenium
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
PATH="C:\Coding_projects\chromedriver.exe"
class AppleWebsite():
    def MAC():
        driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=options)
        driver.get("https://www.apple.com/fr/iphone-12/")
        MAC=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ac-globalnav"]/div/ul[2]/li[3]/a')
        MAC.click()
        time.sleep(random.randint(2,9))
        MAC_AIR=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chapternav"]/div/ul/li[2]/a')
        MAC_AIR.click()
AppleWebsite.MAC()
time.sleep(20)
```